# Operating System Doesnt boot after swapping harddisk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, operating-systems, desktop

let me say i have a Desktop pc[lets say pc **a**] with windows 7 installed at my hard disk ,I just brought another desktop pc[lets say pc **b**] wuth hardisk without operating system.

Now i am transferring just hard disks [**a<-->b**],why doesn't my desktop pc doesnt boot with windows 7 at my desktop pc b?

Is it there any technical reason for not booting[operating system doesnt load] in my machine **b**?

Comment: is one of the PCs UEFI and the other isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you made a simple file by file copy of the system partition. This is not enough.

In order for your PC to boot to Windows, the BIOS/UEFI (the embedded program in the motherboard) needs to know where Windows files are. It does so by reading a special part of the hard drive which tells it where to look for Windows. This part is not a file and cannot be seen while looking at the filesystem.

Possible solutions are:

- Use disk restauration tools (such as Testdisk)
- Make a *full binary* copy of the disk, using either third-party software or GNU/Linux's `dd` command